# thinking-sphinx3 duplicate feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rvm, thinking-sphinx

At some point during installation of thinking-sphinx 3 all rake commands relating to thinking-sphinx tasks return two lines of feedback.  Example

```
MacBook-Pro-di-jerdvo:saim jerdvo$ rake ts:configure
Generating configuration to /Users/jerdvo/r/saim/config/development.sphinx.conf
Generating configuration to /Users/jerdvo/r/saim/config/development.sphinx.conf
```

Other rake tasks are not experiencing the same problem

```
MacBook-Pro-di-jerdvo:saim jerdvo$ rake db:migrate
==  CreateSitesStaticpages: migrating =========================================
-- create_table(:sites_staticpages, {:id=>false})
   -> 0.0894s
==  CreateSitesStaticpages: migrated (0.0900s) ================================

MacBook-Pro-di-jerdvo:saim jerdvo$
```

I suspect it may have something to do with RVM, as I tripped over myself a few times installing and uninstalling.  I expected after uninstalling that new installs would eliminate the duplicate feedback.  Alas, no.

I also wonder whether these actions are being called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your Rakefile?

```
require 'thinking_sphinx/tasks'
```

If you do, remove it - it's not necessary (unless you're on Rails 2), as Rails 3 allows gems to add rake tasks in automatically. People adding this line is usually the reason for the double output.

Comment: That did it.  Tripped myself over multiple times I guess. Wish I could vote the answer up.  Note: this suggestion is not - unless my eyes are on holidays - on the instructions page:  [link]http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/rake_tasks.html